# Waiting for a Blazor component to load variables in bUnit with nUnit

Tags: nunit, blazor, blazor-component, bunit

I am trying to render 'Component A' in my tests, it has the following html inside:

```
@if (functions == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
       <p>loaded</p>
    }
```

'functions' is a variable created in the CS file for the component like so:

```
private List<FunctionViewModel> functions;
```

And populated like so:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await ResetView();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

private async Task ResetView()
        {
            functions = await GetFunctions(Id);
        }
```

Now when I render my component in test I do a markup match:

```
component.WaitForAssertion(() => component.MarkupMatches("<p><em>Loading...</em></p>",
            "Loading markup was no loaded within 10 seconds."), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
```

This passes, but then I do the same type of check but for the 'loaded' markup which should appear when the 'functions' variable is loaded, but it always fails.

Can anyone explain how I can load this component and check it's markup along the way?

Edit:

Full Test Case -

```
[Test]
    public void LoadTitleDivOnMainPage()
    {
        //Act
        IRenderedComponent<UI> component = SetupTestContext.RenderUI(context);

        //Assert
        component.WaitForAssertion(() => component.MarkupMatches("<p><em>Loading...</em></p>",
            "Loading markup was no loaded within 10 seconds."), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

        component.WaitForAssertion(() => component.MarkupMatches("<p>loaded</p>",
            "Loaded markup was no loaded within 10 seconds."), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
        
    }
```

Method to render the UI component -

```
public static IRenderedComponent<UI> RenderUI(TestContext context)
    {

        return context.RenderComponent<UI>();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full testcase?  Because it looks kind of Ok.

Comment: In Test Explorer it shows the exact HTML that _was_ found. (For xUnit anyway).  Maybe you have a small typo.

Comment: Included full test case, I have checked the Markup and it only ever gets to the 'Loading' status

Comment: Fix: loaded vs Loaded.

Comment: Sorry that was an issue with my question, the markup is the same in the test

Comment: "issue with my question" does not encourage to spend more time on this.  Always copy/paste exact code.

Comment: I'm wondering that the first markupmatches works, since you wait for GetFunctions(Id); What is the result of GetFunctions(Id)? Did you debug it?